# Camel-test:Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.RASWsLoggerFactory

Tags: java, junit, apache-camel, cxfrs

I am learning camel-test tool kit for camel-cxf server. As far as I know Junit is used because we can check without server also. but when I run this Junit it is showing me below exception.

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.RASWsLoggerFactory
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:85)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:162)
    at com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory.<clinit>(WsnInitialContextFactory.java:79)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:228)
    at java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:170)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager$3.run(NamingManager.java:873)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager$3.run(NamingManager.java:870)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:229)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.factoryForName(NamingManager.java:869)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.factoryForName(NamingManager.java:820)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:246)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.initializeDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:318)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:348)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.internalInit(InitialContext.java:286)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:211)
    at org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelTestSupport.createJndiContext(CamelTestSupport.java:506)
    at org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelTestSupport.createRegistry(CamelTestSupport.java:492)
    at org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelTestSupport.createCamelContext(CamelTestSupport.java:486)
    at org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelTestSupport.doSetUp(CamelTestSupport.java:246)
    at org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelTestSupport.setUp(CamelTestSupport.java:216)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.RASWsLoggerFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:434)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:665)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:644)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:358)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:627)
    ... 55 more
```

Below is my code:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

import org.apache.camel.EndpointInject;
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.LoggingLevel;
import org.apache.camel.ProducerTemplate;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.component.mock.MockEndpoint;
import org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelTestSupport;
import org.apache.camel.test.spring.CamelSpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.apache.camel.test.spring.DisableJmx;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Ignore;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer;

import com.bac.baclws.ngen.command.AdministerContactPreferencesRequest;
import com.bac.baclws.ngen.command.RetrieveContactPreferencesRequest;

@RunWith(CamelSpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@DisableJmx(true)
//@Ignore
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {

        "classpath:/META-INF/spring/mockTest.xml"
         })
public class DataValidationTest extends CamelTestSupport {
    @EndpointInject(uri="direct:rcp")
    ProducerTemplate template;



    @Test
    public void testQuote() throws Exception {

    String s="<p:Account xmlns:p=\"http://url.xsd\">"
  +"    <p:data>"
  + "   <p:number>30013</p:number>"


  +"    </data>"


  +"       </p:Account>";   
Map<String, Object> headers=new HashMap<String, Object>();

    headers.put("header1", "value1");
    headers.put("header2", "value2");




        template.sendBodyAndHeaders(s, headers);

    }


}

class RCP extends RouteBuilder{

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("direct:rcp")
        .log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, "${body}");

    }

}
```

Below is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf"
    xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf
        http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf/camel-cxf.xsd
        http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd
        http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">



    <cxf:rsServer id="EndPoint"
        address="/PreferenceReporting/account" serviceClass="myEndPoint.EndpointManagement">



    </cxf:rsServer>

    <cxf:rsClient id="EndPointClient"
        address="/PreferenceReporting/account" serviceClass="myEndPoint.EndpointManagement">        
    </cxf:rsClient>


</beans>
```

Please help me out where am going wrong

Answer (score 2):

I think its not a problem with camel ,You added ws.runtime jar in your classpath that is creating the issue ,if you want to run junit along with ws.runtime ,you have to setup your context and JVM based on the ibm jdk ,else you can skip the jar for the unit test case

```
 <plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <classpathDependencyExcludes>
      <classpathDependencyExclude>com.ibm:ws.runtime</classpathDependencyExclude>
      </classpathDependencyExcludes>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins
```

Comment: just an update, for newer versions of the ws.runtime the dependency definition is like this: com.ibm.websphere.ws:com.ibm.ws.runtime